# How to add validators and bootnodes in PoA, when sudo isn't there?

Tags: validator

I'd like to make sure that after `sudo` access is gone forever, there still remains the following functionality in our `PoA` blockchain:

1. new aura and grandpa validators can join.
2. new bootnodes can appear.

I guess, to implement such functionality, we don't need `PoW` or `PoS`, and all can be done with `PoA` combined with some kind of democratic voting among existing participants.

I'm willing to give an opportunity to anyone to become a validator and/or create a bootnode with my zero involvement, so that existing validators by themselves could accept newcomers willing to join.

So the question is: what pallets should I add to the blockchain, how am I supposed to change runtime or node to add such functionality?

The [Private Network tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/) provide the answers only if I fully own the network, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 9):

The bootnodes are configured in the chain spec. When you launch additional nodes, you can add bootnodes for that node.

Have you taken a look at the [node-authorization](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_node_authorization/index.html) pallet? It has a concept of normal nodes, **well-known** nodes, and **sub-nodes** which could fit your use-case.

If you haven't already take a look at the permissioned network tutorial:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/permissioned-network/

[image]

In your use-case, you could set it up so that anyone can claim a peerId and hence a node.

[image]

You can add additional well-known nodes via an extrinsic which can come from sudo **or** governance.

If you want to integrate governance into your chain, I would start by looking into [pallet_collective](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/pallet_collective/index.html) and [pallet_democracy](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/pallet_democracy/index.html).

For example, you can see the governance pallets Kusama is using here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L1391

... in your case you would not need `PhragmenElection` pallet.

Answer (score 5):

For your scenario you might find useful the following pallets:

- [Validator-manager](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/rococo/src/validator_manager.rs) This one is used in Rococo network (PoA).
- [Substrate-validator-set](https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set) Which can be used for add/remove validators in PoA networks.